# Are there more people answering than asking?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers

I get the impression that there are more people *answering* questions than *asking* questions. I realize the Stack Exchange family of sites are extremely popular and gaining reputation has become a sort of currency, thus the sheer number of people *hunting* for new questions, but if I am correct, how could there be more people with answers than people with questions?

Comment: Because people who ask also answer.

Comment: People that ask questions generally don't have all that many questions. People that answer usually can answer know answers to more than one question. There are more people asking questions than answering them, I'd say. Loads of people each asking few questions, fewer people each answering multple questions. No evidence, just personal observations.

Comment: Back-of-the-envelope, about 3000 SO users post answers to 35000 questions in a week.

Comment: The observation that fewer people are answering; but they post more in general (due to multiple answers/day) bears out when you look at the reputation distribution. Very few users are high rep (compared to the total), and answering is the best way to get reputation. Clearly more people are asking than answering.

Comment: There are more answers than questions, but not more people answering than people asking.  The number of people who ask at least one question on Stack Overflow far outnumber the ones answering questions. If you doubt this, just spend 5 minutes observing the front page.

Comment: Answering is easier than asking.

Comment: @Renan Only when you know the answer! Asking *well* is certainly hard, but for those without much knowledge; answering is much harder.

Comment: Also consider that questions are technically a limited resource. "How do I print to console?" can typically be only asked once before additional start getting marked as duplicate, but you can get a dozen answers and those will usually not get flagged.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That is an important distinction I overlooked.

Comment: I'd reword it to 'Are there people more answering that asking?'

Comment: @Lankymart literally yes, but it shows the other perspective

Comment: I find this is the case on popular tags like "php" where there are a lot of basic questions, everyone can answer these. Once you see a more complicated question you see the answer rate drop to about 0.

Comment: People who answer questions can usually answer their own questions, too, and thus don't even ask most of their questions.

Comment: Asking a question is more difficult than answering one

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Yes, indeed.

Comment: I haven't yet asked a question. Not because I have no questions, but because I have found the answers I require by searching first.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Look at the badges:

**Student** Asked first question with score of 1 or more - 970.5k awarded

**Teacher** Answered first question with score of 1 or more - 682.9k awarded

It's not precise, because counts only questions and answers with score 1+.

So counting distinct people it seems that there are more askers.

But many questions have many answers. Many people leave their answer as an alternative to accepted answer or provide improvement to existing answers.

Comment: And obviously 1 question can have zero to many answers but its never the other way around.

It would also be interesting to know the number of unanswered questions.

Comment: @MarcelBurkhard: Oh, I don't know.  Some of the answers don't belong to the question where the answer is posted.

Answer (score 53):

Over the past year 461,735 people have posted at least one answer.
Over the past year 755,385 people have posted at least one question.

([Here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/248516) is the query.)

(Note that there is of course an overlap between those two, as some people have posted an answer and a question.  Deleted questions are also not in the data explorer.)

You can adjust the timespan on the query to see what these ratios looked like at different points in time.

Comment: You might want to take a whole year, but spare the last month or two to drop most crap. Though that would probably move the ratio some to the answerers...

Comment: @Deduplicator I fooled around a bit with a few different date ranges and the differences in the ratio were small enough for anything remotely recent that it didn't seem worth worrying too much about.

Answer (score 0):

That means there are many easy questions :)

Comment: every person has different easyness level. one person's hard question is easy for others.